# How can i use string instead of file when I want to decrypte with elgamal?

Tags: java, netbeans, elgamal

I want to use ElGamal encryption. I can do it with a `File`, but I don't know how to do it with a `String`.

Like this:

```
public static String decrypt(String encrypted_sql) {
  File f = new File(sPrFile);

  ElGamalPrivateKey elpr = null;
    try {
      elpr = new ElGamalPrivateKey(sPrFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR : " +e x.getLocalizedMessage() +
        "\n kullanıcı : "+username+"\n password : "+password);
      Logger.getLogger(ppi_script_execute.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ElGamalAlgorithm.decrypt2(encrypted_sql, elpr);
  }
```

}

I don't want to use `sPrFile`. I want to use `String` variable. My key is like this :

```
Key 600 d99f0d547sdfs6d8f49sd96f65sd1f3827af14a34654dbb285fcbc8019df1fd7c152d5e25
        7157f53e2‌​0d4613b270a7b656790c5a723a88asdasd58d6fe2dd0dd810365b8574c253be2
        26e7da90eb61578eb197e764761f7e6955009f7d6339245244044bd7301e40ee3f423fef6
        26cc35c86fc7‌6716db47d85ecff5a5dd3bd8655sdf8sd6f6sd6f86sd4f65686w9w9e46sd5
        f65s6d6s4d6f6ss6df 4546cfe42842c82cb9cda6b954632ae8201dcde3b6af0bbd7‌​61879
        zzf89yfdd28db4bca70ss48w16fc8ff7e38a40dfc05f48caaffcc61d1972ff0b3
```

Comment: Seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894882/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-text-files-using-elgamal ?

Comment: I want to give private key from String variable not file

Comment: Oh my bad :) I was thinking the other way around, maybe this will be helpfull: http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/DSAElGamalKeyRingGenerator.java.html

Comment: I hope you did not just pasted production key in here ;) and back to the topic why you are not using JCA and let us say bouncycastle as provider ?

Comment: I dont want to use file.Because file is on computer and anybody can find it

Comment: If you've given them the program, the string is also on the computer and anyone can find that, too.

Comment: Could you point us to the javadoc of the elgamal API you're using?